# Search a list of strings in a column where each cell contains multiple values

Tags: excel, vba, list, full-text-search

I have a column where each cell has multiple strings divided by a "/". I have as well a list of strings.

I want to search for each item of the list in the column and each time that I find an item write in another column with the addition of the Shortname next to it.

Each one of those columns are in different worksheets.

Something like the image below:

The first column is where I want to search, the second is what I want to search, and the third is the resulting column.
For every string that starts with "GPRF_", I want to write it in the third column with the Shortname associated to it.
In this example "GPRF_TxChPower" appears 3 times, so it is written 3 times with each Shortname associated to it before passing to the next item.

Example
[image]

For now, I used this line:

```
IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G35;TestConfigs!$B$3&"|||"&TestConfigs!$B$4&"|||"&TestConfigs!$B$5&"|||"&TestConfigs!$B$6&"|||"&TestConfigs!$B$7&"|||"&TestConfigs!$B$8&"|||"&TestConfigs!$B$9&"|||"&TestConfigs!$B$10&"|||"&TestConfigs!$B$11));1;0)
```

That basically searches what I want(G35), which is in the worksheet Commun, in the column(B3:11) on the worksheet TestConfigs, if it is found returns 1 else 0 to the cell (F35), also in the worksheet Commun.

And then in the column I want the values to be written I did:

```
=IF(Commun!F35=1;Commun!G35;"")
```

If the result in F35 is 1, I write what is written in G35, else "".

Comment: *I want to write it in the third column the number of times that item is found* Check COUNTIF with wildcards. Probably something like `=COUNTIF(list_of_values,"*GPRF_TxChPower*")` should work

Comment: Not so clear what you want. At least for me... So, searching for strings starting with `GPRF_` shouldn't it be enough? Is it a possibility that other strings **starting with this prefix to not exist in Worksheet2, but be found in  Worksheet1**? I mean something as `GPRF_Test`... Then, what to understand from the returned `GPRF_TxPhaseNoise_ABD`? Where from `ABD` has come?

Comment: @FaneDuru thanks, you are right, it's easier just going by the prefix. I got mistook with the different solutions I was thinking about this morning.
And the 'ABD' was a typo, thanks for saying, I will correct it

Comment: @FaneDuru

Hello, How can I change the code in the case where the column ShortName has multiple values ?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean... Show an example, please. Of  how this ShortName should be and the way to be returned. But, since this is something else, I would suggest you to place another question, where to post my code and explaining what is to be done, in terms of data to be processed change and the way to return. If you tag me here I will help, when I will be available, if somebody else did not solve the problem in the meantime...

Comment: @FaneDuru I managed here. Thank you for the help. Your code is really well written

Comment: I tried commenting everything in a way to be understood, but I cannot understand what you meant.. Are these „multiple values” separated by a character and you need running the code for each?

Comment: @FaneDuru yes, for example they are separated by "/". I added a second loop inside. It worked here.
I can put here if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. It uses only two sheets, processing against "GPRF_" prefix. Using arrays and working mostly in memory, it should be very fast. It assumes that the range to be processed has the headers on the second row and cells to be iterated starting from the third row. It returns in the `Next` sheet. It may return anywhere if you correctly `Set` `sh2`...

```
 Sub ExtractShortNameByPrefix()
   Dim sh1 As Worksheet, lastR As Long, sh2 As Worksheet, arr, arrCell
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, dict As Object
   
   Const strPref As String = "GPRF_" 'prefix to be searched for
   Const colToReturn As Long = 1    'column number where to return the processed array
   
   Set sh1 = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet to be processed (your Worksheet1)
   Set sh2 = sh1.Next    'use here the sheet where to return (your Worksheet3)
   lastR = sh1.Range("A" & sh1.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row
   arr = sh1.Range("A3:B" & lastR).Value2 'place the range in an array for faster iteration and processing
   
   Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   
   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If InStr(arr(i, 1), strPref) > 0 Then
            arrCell = Split(arr(i, 1), "/") 'split the string by "/" separator if prefix exists
            For j = 0 To UBound(arrCell)
                If left(arrCell(j), Len(strPref)) = strPref Then
                    dict(arrCell(j) & "_" & arr(i, 2)) = 1 'place in the dictionay as key UNIQUE concatenations...
                End If
            Next j
        End If
   Next i
   'drop the processed dictionary keys:
   With sh2.cells(2, colToReturn).Resize(dict.count, 1)
        .Value2 = Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)
        .cells(1, 1).Offset(-1).value = strPref
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
   End With
```

You can change "strPrefix" and "columnToReturn" constants to process a different prefix and return in a different column...

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will test it. And see what returns

Comment: YES, thank you so much. That's exactly it!

I'm trying just to change the input columns bc the list of items are in B3:B11 and the shortname  in E3:E11.

And the worksheet to return I changed, but I didn't manage to see how I can return the list for let's say column B beginning in row 3.

But thank you so much, I will also implement a case for the prefix and worksheet, because I have 4 other worksheets.

Comment: @Mateus Santos Valença When you have different ranges to be processed it is good to show them to us as they are... If "list of items" means the column with the strings separated by "/", you should only adapt `lastR` calculation and  `arr` range: `arr = sh1.Range("B3:E" & lastR).Value2`. Then you will replace `dict(arrCell(j) & "_" & arr(i,2)) = 1` with  `dict(arrCell(j) & "_" & arr(i,4)) = 1`. (the fourth array column).

Comment: Alright, next times I will do like that to help more. Thank you for the help, your code is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not get you question right, but if you want to find how many times one text is repeated in other text you can use this:

```
=(LEN(B3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B3,B4,"")))/LEN(B4)
```

where B3 is long text, and B4 is text to search.